# G+ deprecation with refresh tokens

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

We are wondering someone could answer the following question about the deprecation of scopes. Currently during the OAuth process for YouTube registration, we are asking for the following scopes (as well as offline access) using the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth endpoint :

- youtube
- plus.login
- youtube.readonly
- youtube.upload
- youtubepartner
- youtubepartner-channel-audit
- youtube.force-ssl

With the announcement of the G+ deprecation, during the YouTube Oauth flow, we replaced :

- plus.login

with :

- userinfo.profile

Our questions are :

What is the expected behavior of our refresh tokens for refreshing access tokens offline for the existing accounts that have been OAuth-ed before we made the above scope change ? Do we expect these to fail on March 7, or would they continue to be able to refresh and just have no access to any endpoints that required the scope ? We want to make sure we understand what information we need to relay to customers about this change with respect to our current YouTube implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the expected behavior of our refresh tokens for refreshing access tokens offline for the existing accounts that have been OAuth-ed before we made the above scope change?

If you make changes to your scopes then you should do a force prompt to request authorization of your users again.   This way they will see userinfo.profile now and you will have new refresh tokens that you can use containing the correct consents.

> Do we expect these to fail on March 7, or would they continue to be able to refresh and just have no access to any endpoints that required the scope?

Any refresh token you have now should continue to work just fine. However any requests that you make against anything that would have used plus.login will fail as you do not have access to that anymore.